How to list all vertex of a one-cycle graph in order (cw or ccw)?
Assuming I have a graph with a single cycle below, I want to list the vertices of this cycle in order. Whether it's clockwise (CW) or counterclockwise (CCW) is okay, as long as we are consistent. So the result could be one of something like this: 
{9, 7, 8, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6} (CW) or {9, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 8, 7} (CCW), or any other sequence that starts from a different node.
cycle = {6 \[UndirectedEdge] 9, 9 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 
   7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
   5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6};
Graph[cycle, VertexLabels -> "Name"]



FindHamiltonianPath[cycle]


{7, 9, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 8}



cycle = UndirectedEdge @@@ 
   RandomSample[
    RandomSample /@ {{6, 9}, {9, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 3}, {3, 1}, {1, 
       2}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}}];
gr = Graph[cycle, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
FindCycle[gr][[1, All, 1]]


{5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 8, 7, 9, 6}

Talking about CW or CCW has no sense since it depends on graph layout.
